# How to build a nonblocking Consumer when using AsyncRabbitTemplate with Request/Reply Pattern

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm new to rabbitmq and currently trying to implement a nonblocking producer with a nonblocking consumer. I've build some test producer where I played around with typereference:

```
@Service
public class Producer {
    @Autowired
    private AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncRabbitTemplate;

    public <T extends RequestEvent<S>, S> RabbitConverterFuture<S> asyncSendEventAndReceive(final T event) {
        return asyncRabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceiveAsType(QueueConfig.EXCHANGE_NAME, event.getRoutingKey(), event, event.getResponseTypeReference());
    }
}
```

And in some other place the test function that gets called in a RestController

```
@Autowired
Producer producer;

public void test() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    TestEvent requestEvent = new TestEvent("SOMEDATA");
    RabbitConverterFuture<TestResponse> reply = producer.asyncSendEventAndReceive(requestEvent);
    log.info("Hello! The Reply is: {}", reply.get());
}
```

This so far was pretty straightforward, where I'm stuck now is how to create a consumer which is non-blocking too. My current listener:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = QueueConfig.QUEUENAME)
public TestResponse onReceive(TestEvent event) {
    Future<TestResponse> replyLater = proccessDataLater(event.getSomeData())
    return replyLater.get();
}
```

As far as I'm aware, when using @RabbitListener this listener runs in its own thread. And I could configure the MessageListener to use more then one thread for the active listeners. Because of that, blocking the listener thread with future.get() is not blocking the application itself. Still there might be the case where all threads are blocking now and new events are stuck in the queue, when they maybe dont need to. What I would like to do is to just receive the event without the need to instantly return the result. Which is probably not possible with @RabbitListener. Something like:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = QueueConfig.QUEUENAME)
public void onReceive(TestEvent event) {
   /* 
    * Some fictional RabbitMQ API call where i get a ReplyContainer which contains
    * the CorrelationID for the event. I can call replyContainer.reply(testResponse) later 
    * in the code without blocking the listener thread
    */        
    ReplyContainer replyContainer = AsyncRabbitTemplate.getReplyContainer()

    // ProcessDataLater calls reply on the container when done with its action
    proccessDataLater(event.getSomeData(), replyContainer);
}
```

What is the best way to implement such behaviour with rabbitmq in spring?

EDIT Config Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitMQConfig implements RabbitListenerConfigurer {

    public static final String topicExchangeName = "exchange";

    @Bean
    TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(topicExchangeName);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHost("localhost");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2MessageConverter consumerJackson2MessageConverter() {
        return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(rabbitConnectionFactory());
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(producerJackson2MessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncRabbitTemplate() {
        return new AsyncRabbitTemplate(rabbitTemplate());
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("test", false);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue()).to(exchange()).with("foo.#");
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory myRabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(5);
        factory.setMessageConverter(producerJackson2MessageConverter());
        factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
        return factory;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureRabbitListeners(final RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        registrar.setContainerFactory(myRabbitListenerContainerFactory());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have time to test it right now, but something like this should work; presumably you don't want to lose messages so you need to set the ackMode to MANUAL and do the acks yourself (as shown).

**UPDATE**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So52173111Application {

    private final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate template;

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncTemplate) {
        return args -> {
            RabbitConverterFuture<Object> future = asyncTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("foo", "test");
            future.addCallback(r -> {
                System.out.println("Reply: " + r);
            }, t -> {
                t.printStackTrace();
            });
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncTemplate(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return new AsyncRabbitTemplate(template);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
    public void listen(String in, Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag,
            @Header(AmqpHeaders.CORRELATION_ID) String correlationId,
            @Header(AmqpHeaders.REPLY_TO) String replyTo) {

        ListenableFuture<String> future = handleInput(in);
        future.addCallback(result -> {
            Address address = new Address(replyTo);
            this.template.convertAndSend(address.getExchangeName(), address.getRoutingKey(), result, m -> {
                m.getMessageProperties().setCorrelationId(correlationId);
                return m;
            });
            try {
                channel.basicAck(tag, false);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, t -> {
            t.printStackTrace();
        });
    }

    private ListenableFuture<String> handleInput(String in) {
        SettableListenableFuture<String> future = new SettableListenableFuture<String>();
        exec.execute(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            future.set(in.toUpperCase());
        });
        return future;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So52173111Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I've implemented your code but im getting an AmqpReplyTimeoutException for the Producer. The Consumer gets the Message and acks. I'm using the folling Producer Call: `RabbitConverterFuture<String> test = template.convertSendAndReceiveAsType("exchange",
    "foo.bar", "hello world", new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>() {
    });`. I will edit my post with the config class.

Comment: When im using a normal RabbitTemplate instead of an async-one for sendAndReceive i get the error: No correlation header in reply. Passing the correlationData to this.template.convertAndSend in the consumer didnt solved it.

Comment: See the update to my answer; we should probably build this capability into the framework.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. This time it worked. I will add a feature request for this to be in the framework. (I dont have enough reputation to upvote your answer, sry for that)

Comment: Thanks; work is already in progress to add it to the framework https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-832.